# How to outdent a block with emacs?

Tags: emacs

I can use C-x TAB for indenting 1 column, or C-u N C-x TAB for N columns.

How can I `outdent' a block with emacs?

Comment: I'm using XHTML mode, but I expect there should be some mode-independent way.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You do the same, since C-x tab understands negative arguments.

So to outdent 3 columns:

`C-u - 3 C-x TAB`

Answer (score 7):

In python mode, for a marked region you also use C-c-< to outdent and C-c-> to indent

Answer (score 3):

Use rectangular operations. C-x r k - to kill a rectangle.

Comment: Select a rectangle one column wide (it will show as if you selected several lines). Then C-x r k.

Comment: Alternatively, if you enable `(cua-selection-mode 1)` then you can use its more advanced & visual rectangle editing abilities. Just type `C-RET` and move `down` as many lines as you want to outdent, and then just `delete` until you're happy.

Answer (score 3):

Just like you mention for indenting:

C-u N C-x TAB

Just use a negative N:

C-u -N C-x TAB